# innerHTML alternative for firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, innerhtml

I am filling html table with following line of code

Javascript:

```
var newTR = document.createElement("TR");
var newTD;

    newTD = document.createElement("TD");
    newTD.width = "22%"

    newTD.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='AppOrderTxt1' readOnly='true'"+  
     "' id='AppOrderTxt' value=' test'  class='text-noborders' onFocus='this.blur()' size='3'/>";

    newTR.appendChild(newTD);

    if(document.all){
        tblRCRPCombo.children[0].appendChild(newTR);
    }else{

       tblRCRPCombo.insertRow(tblRCRPCombo.rows.length);                           
       tblRCRPCombo.rows[tblRCRPCombo.rows.length-1].innerHTML=newTR.innerHTML;
    }
```

When i am trying to get the request parameter value by name `AppOrderTxt1`, it returns `null` in FireFox, while same thing is working in IE.

Comment: Does the input appear in the HTML page? Does it work if you fix the syntax error (there is an extra quote before the id attribute)?

Comment: i have remove that extra quote but it can't make any difference

Answer (score 2):

Might not be a problem but you have an extra `'` in there:

```
newTD.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='AppOrderTxt1' readOnly='true'"+  
     " id='AppOrderTxt' value=' test'  class='text-noborders' onFocus='this.blur()' size='3'/>";
```

Also, the first if statement is working in firefox, but firefox won't enter that because of (document.all). If you only have this row...

`tblRCRPCombo.children[0].appendChild(newTR);`

...instead of the whole if else statement, then it will work in FF and IE.

Here's why: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ

> Some proprietary document objects such as document.all and
>   document.layers are not part of the W3C DOM and are not supported in
>   Mozilla. (There is partial undetectable support for document.all,
>   though, in newer versions of Mozilla. However, that functionality only
>   exists for compatibility with sites authored specifically for IE. You
>   should not rely on Mozilla’s document.all support on new pages.) The
>   method **document.getElementById()** can be used instead.

Comment: I have remove that extra quote and if condition also but still it can't make any difference

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CvK5R/6/ This works for me in both FF 10 and IE 8. Might be a silly question but have you declared the `tblRCRPCombo` variable?

Answer (score -1):

Replace `innerHTML` by `textContent`:

```
tblRCRPCombo.rows[tblRCRPCombo.rows.length-1].textContent = newTR.textContent;
```